# Returning custom values based on query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make a query that returns a different custom value based on a query? Here is an example:

What I have in the table ...

| number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

... and this is what I want returned:

| number |
| --- |
| one |
| two |
| three |

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a `case` statement. Depending on your flavor of SQL, something like this should work:

```
select 
    bar = case 
               when foo = 1 then 'one'
               when foo = 2 then 'two'
               else 'baz' 
          end
from myTable
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select value = case t.value
               when 1 then 'one'
               when 2 then 'two'
               when 3 then 'three'
               ...
               else null
               end
from my_table t
```